# Laravel route variable, foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I wan't to print all forums with foreach in laravel. I'm trying to write code:

```
Route::get('', function()
{
        return View::make('home', array(
                $forums = DB::table('select * from forums')
        ));
});
```

And then in template write foreach:

```
  @foreach ($forums as $forum)
    <p>This is forum {{ $forum->name }}</p><br>
  @endforeach
```

But it's not working, it prints:

> Undefined variable: forums (View: C:\myadmin\htdocs\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing what you inted to do is the following :

```
Route::get('', function()
{
    return View::make('home', array(
            $forums = DB::table('forums')->select()->get()
    ));
});
```